# VFY unable to resolve static method

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, flickr

I've tried many methods of having Flickr's API to work in my Android app but no matter what I try to do (Maven, copying the jar to /libs folder, importing external jar as a library) nothing seems to work and I am presented with this error:

`12-20 11:16:24.641: D/dalvikvm(1568): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-20 11:16:24.641: I/dalvikvm(1568): Could not find method org.slf4j.Logger.isDebugEnabled, referenced from method com.googlecode.flickrjandroid.REST.sendUpload
12-20 11:16:24.641: W/dalvikvm(1568): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 13907: Lorg/slf4j/Logger;.isDebugEnabled ()Z
12-20 11:16:24.641: D/dalvikvm(1568): VFY: replacing opcode 0x78 at 0x0002
12-20 11:16:24.641: W/dalvikvm(1568): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lcom/googlecode/flickrjandroid/REST;
12-20 11:16:24.641: D/AndroidRuntime(1568): Shutting down VM
12-20 11:16:24.641: W/dalvikvm(1568): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41cbb300)
12-20 11:16:24.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1568): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 11:16:24.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1568): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
12-20 11:16:24.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at com.googlecode.flickrjandroid.Flickr.<init>(Flickr.java:223)
12-20 11:16:24.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at com.googlecode.flickrjandroid.Flickr.<init>(Flickr.java:247)
12-20 11:16:24.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at com.triandria.layouts.MainActivityLayout.changeBackgroundPicture(MainActivityLayout.java:152)`

Comment: Seems you are missing flickrj-android* jar at runtime?

Comment: Not really, unless I am missing something. I tried copying the jar to the /libs folder I created. Didn't work. I tried having the jar in my build path as an external jar then ticked it on Imports/Exports. Didn't work. Tried making my app a Maven project and then fetched the artifact from the maven's repository. Didn't work. I am presented with the same error. ( I downloaded a previous version of Flickr's API whitch I am about to test in a minute to see if the error is replicated.)

Comment: That's because there is a dependency mismatch as well between your libs and slf4j.